# while loop php in sql tablle

Tags: php, sql

With this program shown below, the program cannot print the table the the data shown in the php file. I need your help to see what problem in my sql and the table.

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(thedate, '%Y %M %D') AS d, count(semail) AS av FROM `ecard2008` WHERE `sflag`='1' AND `thedate`>='2000-12-12' GROUP BY `thedate`")or die(mysql_error());

  echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Daily Volume</th>
        <th>Sent</th>
        <th>Pending</th>
        </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['d'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['av']  . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['av']  . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['av']  . "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
      }
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: did you echo and run this query directly in phpmyadmin?

Comment: yes do you get any error from the query?

Comment: yes as answers below you should use mysql_ or mysqli_. not both

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_` commands. Stick with `mysqli_`, the `mysql_` commands are becoming depracated and will be removed in future PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

You execute query using `mysql_` and in while loop you are using `mysqli_`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that the result from mysql_query will work with the mysqli_* functions, and you should move away from using mysql_query anyway as [the mysql_* functions are officially deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-db-query.php).

You are better off to use either pdo or the mysqli_ functions.